# Calculating the range of all rows in data set in R

Tags: r, vector, range

I have a data set `x` consists of 4 columns. When I apply `range(x)` I receive one answer for all rows. How can I get the range for each row of the 4 columns without using loops?

Comment: Why did I get -1 on this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical case for functions of the *apply-family, which are technically loops with a special syntax. In your case, you can use

```
apply(X = x, MARGIN = 1, FUN = range)
```

This tells R to apply the function range() over all rows, as expressed by MARGIN = 1 (MARGIN = 2 would be the same over all columns).